# How to print Japanese character in windows Japanese system?

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio, cjk

I have written a small program that will take Japanese string as the hardcoded values and will write it into the file in the Japanese system. The program is written in visual studio 2010(english system)

```
char szMsg_m[]="スプールがいっぱいです";  //input
string szMsg_s=("スプールがいっぱいです");
wchar_t szMsg_w[]=L"スプールがいっぱいです";
wstring szMsg_h=L"スプールがいっぱいです";

fprintf (trace.TraceFP, "\tMsg:%s \n", szMsg_m); //output
fprintf (trace.TraceFP, "\tMsg:%s \n", szMsg_s.c_str());
fwprintf (trace.TraceFP, L"\tMsg:%s \n", szMsg_w);
fwprintf (trace.TraceFP, L"\tMsg:%s \n", szMsg_h.c_str());
```

The output should be Japanese why it is coming as (?) when I am running the exe in Japanese system

Comment: What encodings are you using in 1.) source file, and 2.) output device/file?

Comment: BTW, you are not programming in C.  The C language does not have the `std::string` data type.  Please update your tags accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

As *user694733* pointed out, you are missing the `std::locale::global (std::locale ("en_US.UTF-8"));`. I tested the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    std::locale::global (std::locale ("en_US.UTF-8"));
    char szMsg_m[]="スプールがいっぱいです";  //input
    std::string szMsg_s=("スプールがいっぱいです");

    fprintf (stdout, "\tMsg:%s \n", szMsg_m); //output
    fprintf (stdout, "\tMsg:%s \n", szMsg_s.c_str());    
    return 0;
}
```

which produces the output:

> Msg:スプールがいっぱいです
>
> Msg:スプールがいっぱいです

What I cannot tell, without more information is, what `trace.TraceFP` in your code is, and how to use it.

What also works is the following:

```
{
    std::locale::global (std::locale ("en_US.UTF-8"));
    wchar_t szMsg_w[]=L"スプールがいっぱいです";
    std::wstring szMsg_h=L"スプールがいっぱいです";
    fwprintf (stdout, L"\tMsg:%ls \n", szMsg_w);
    fwprintf (stdout, L"\tMsg:%ls \n", szMsg_h.c_str());
}
```

Notice that the correct format for the wide-strings is `%ls`.

which produces the output:

> Msg:スプールがいっぱいです
>
> Msg:スプールがいっぱいです

Comment: I tried this in the windows visual studio or dev c++ getting runtime error because of line: std::locale::global (std::locale ("en_US.UTF-8"));

Comment: What does the error actually say? If you can, copy that error output and post into your question as an edit. How about that?

Comment: Does it say, something about a missing `dll` file? Could you try running the program from the command line. `CTRL+R` --> `cmd`. In the command prompt you could navigate to where the binary is generated and run it from there. Same error or different error?